# Change the Right Margin of a View Programmatically?

Tags: android, layout, textview

Can this attribute be changed dynamically in Java code?

```
android:layout_marginRight
```

I have a `TextView`, that has to change its position some pixels to the left dynamically.

How to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 526, accepted):

EDIT: A more generic way of doing this that doesn't rely on the layout type (other than that it is a layout type which supports margins):

```
public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
        v.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

You should check the docs for [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). Basically, you'll want to get the TextView's LayoutParams object, and modify the margins, then set it back to the TextView. Assuming it's in a LinearLayout, try something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I can't test it right now, so my casting may be off by a bit, but the LayoutParams are what need to be modified to change the margin.

#### NOTE

> Don't forget that if your TextView is inside, for example, a
> ***RelativeLayout***, one should use ***RelativeLayout.LayoutParams*** instead of
> LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Just to elaborate in your answer in case other people are looking for this. If you are creating the TextView programmatically then you need to create a new LinearLayout.LayoutParams object too, instead of trying to get one out via .getLayoutParams();

Comment: This works awesome, and it seems like it sets the margins in pixels.  Is it possible to set it in dp?

Comment: @KKendall: Just [convert your DP to PX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6327095/321697) first.

Comment: As per your NOTE: I have doubt. If the textview or a button is inside a table row? Then what should I use instead of Relative Layout, Table Layout?

Comment: Related to the note, you can just cast tv.getLayoutParams() to ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams. This way it doesn't matter what layout is the parrent, as long as it implements margins

Comment: Now you can define your margin in different dimensions files and read it from there.
`getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.your_margin)`

Comment: if you don't know the container layout, how would you proceed? like the container could be LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ContraintLayout etc... the reason I ask this, is because it could crash if the container layout type changes in the future, it should really not cause problems for children margins.

Comment: @TatiOverflow the answer that checks for MarginLayoutParams will not cause a crash. The type of the container doesn't matter, provided it's a layout that supports margins (i.e. its `LayoutParams` extend from `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`). If they do not, then at worst, your margins will not be adjusted.

Comment: Easy way to convert int to dp -> int * resources.displayMetrics.density. Resources class is available everywhere where you also have context.

Comment: To set the marginStart and marginEnd use `p.setMarginStart(l);` and `p.setMarginEnd(r);`

Answer (score 52):

#### Update: Android KTX

The [Core KTX module](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#core) provides extensions for common libraries that are part of the Android framework, [`androidx.core.view`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary) among them.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:{latest-version}"
}
```

The following extension functions are handy to deal with margins:

> Note: they are all extension functions of `MarginLayoutParams`, so
> first you need to get and cast the `layoutParams` of your view:
>
> ```
> val params = (myView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)
> ```

- **[`setMargins()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#setmargins) extension function:**

Sets the margins of all axes in the `ViewGroup`'s `MarginLayoutParams`. (The dimension has to be provided in pixels, see the last section if you want to work with dp)

```
inline fun MarginLayoutParams.setMargins(@Px size: Int): Unit
// E.g. 16px margins
params.setMargins(16)
```

- **[`updateMargins()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#updatemargins) extension function:**

Updates the margins in the `ViewGroup`'s `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`.

```
inline fun MarginLayoutParams.updateMargins(
    @Px left: Int = leftMargin, 
    @Px top: Int = topMargin, 
    @Px right: Int = rightMargin, 
    @Px bottom: Int = bottomMargin
): Unit
// Example: 8px left margin 
params.updateMargins(left = 8)
```

- **[`updateMarginsRelative()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#updatemarginsrelative) extension function:**

Updates the relative margins in the `ViewGroup`'s `MarginLayoutParams` (start/end instead of left/right).

```
inline fun MarginLayoutParams.updateMarginsRelative(
    @Px start: Int = marginStart, 
    @Px top: Int = topMargin, 
    @Px end: Int = marginEnd, 
    @Px bottom: Int = bottomMargin
): Unit
// E.g: 8px start margin 
params.updateMargins(start = 8)
```

The following extension properties are handy to get the current margins:

```
inline val View.marginBottom: Int
inline val View.marginEnd: Int
inline val View.marginLeft: Int
inline val View.marginRight: Int
inline val View.marginStart: Int
inline val View.marginTop: Int
// E.g: get margin bottom
val bottomPx = myView1.marginBottom
```

- Using `dp` instead of `px`:

If you want to work with `dp` (density-independent pixels) instead of `px`, you will need to convert them first. You can easily do that with the following extension property:

```
val Int.px: Int
    get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

Then you can call the previous extension functions like:

```
params.updateMargins(start = 16.px, end = 16.px, top = 8.px, bottom = 8.px)
val bottomDp = myView1.marginBottom.dp
```

---

*Old answer:*

In Kotlin you can declare an extension function like:

```
fun View.setMargins(
    leftMarginDp: Int? = null,
    topMarginDp: Int? = null,
    rightMarginDp: Int? = null,
    bottomMarginDp: Int? = null
) {
    if (layoutParams is ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        val params = layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        leftMarginDp?.run { params.leftMargin = this.dpToPx(context) }
        topMarginDp?.run { params.topMargin = this.dpToPx(context) }
        rightMarginDp?.run { params.rightMargin = this.dpToPx(context) }
        bottomMarginDp?.run { params.bottomMargin = this.dpToPx(context) }
        requestLayout()
    }
}

fun Int.dpToPx(context: Context): Int {
    val metrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, this.toFloat(), metrics).toInt()
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
myView1.setMargins(8, 16, 34, 42)
```

Or:

```
myView2.setMargins(topMarginDp = 8)
```

Comment: for first answer add complete code example please

Comment: what do you mean? there are examples for all of them

Comment: `params` varaibble was missed in code but i found it with first case and not in other 
Now your answer is fully descriptive

Answer (score 18):

Use LayoutParams (as explained already). However be careful which LayoutParams to choose. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11971553/3184778 "you need to use the one that relates to the PARENT of the view you're working on, not the actual view"

If for example the TextView is inside a TableRow, then you need to use TableRow.LayoutParams instead of RelativeLayout or LinearLayout

Comment: it really sucks that you have to know the textbox destination in order to set the margins... you'd think there would be a solution that is destination independent.

Answer (score 12):

**Use This function to set all Type of margins**

```
      public void setViewMargins(Context con, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params,      
       int left, int top , int right, int bottom, View view) {

    final float scale = con.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // convert the DP into pixel
    int pixel_left = (int) (left * scale + 0.5f);
    int pixel_top = (int) (top * scale + 0.5f);
    int pixel_right = (int) (right * scale + 0.5f);
    int pixel_bottom = (int) (bottom * scale + 0.5f);

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams s = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) params;
    s.setMargins(pixel_left, pixel_top, pixel_right, pixel_bottom);

    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Why the additional 0.5f?

Comment: @behelit I know this is late but for anyone looking... when you cast a float to an int, the float rounds.  0.0 -> 0.4 rounds to 0 while 0.5 -> 0.9 rounds to 1.  This can create inconsistencies in the final ints.  To prevent this, adding 0.5 ensures all rounding is to 1.  Why?  say your float is 0.3: 0.3 + 0.5 = 0.8 which rounds UP to 1.  Say your float is 0.8: 0.8 + 0.5 = 1.3 which rounds DOWN to 1.  Now you can be safe in your knowledge of the final rounding (SIDE NOTE: we add 0.5 rather than subtract to avoid getting a negative int)