# How to add space between dynamically created buttons in android

Tags: android, button, spaces

i have dynamically created lot of buttons.How to add spaces between two buttons. please help me. Thanks in advance

**My code:**

```
private LinearLayout LLDynamic;

 private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ParaOne;

ParaOne = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(280, 30);

Button button1= new Button(Twindo_fromEditGroup.this);
button1.setTextSize(16);


LLDynamic = new LinearLayout(Twindo_fromEditGroup.this); 
LLDynamic.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LLDynamic.addView(button1,ParaOne);
```

Comment: Add margins .....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472429/change-the-right-margin-of-a-view-programmatically

Answer (score 5):

Use LayoutParams [Study here for LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

You can Use RelativeLayout Params also [See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Then you can use setMargins().  Last set These values to your dynamically created button. I am not posting any code. Code example has been given in Nunu's post.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
params.setLayoutParams(urButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add margins..for example..

```
Button button1 = new Button(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams rel_button1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
rel_button1.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
button1.setLayoutParams(rel_button1);
```