# Modify margin params in code

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing an interface to Android app. This is my view in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DISTANCIAS TX"
                    android:textSize="16dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
                    android:text="COORDENADAS"
                    android:textSize="16dip" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TX 21KHz:"
                    android:textColor="#DB3F3F"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
                    android:text="X:"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TX 23KHz:"
                    android:textColor="#EFC745"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
                    android:text="Y:"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TX 25KHz:"
                    android:textColor="#53FF49"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
                    android:text="Z:"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TX 27KHz:"
                    android:textColor="#496BFF"
                    android:textSize="20dip" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want modify params of tablelayout, in concret margintop, because first i do some operations to calculate pixels that will be surface. so how can i modify this params in my on create?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472429/change-the-right-margin-of-a-view-programmatically

Comment: yes, i read this, but not works for me... I need changes all table layout

Comment: are you saying that the default implementation of ´TableRow.LayoutParams` doesn't work?

Comment: No.. but i want modify all TableLayout, not TableRow

Comment: in your code you are applying the margin to the TextTiews. And the TableRows are the parents of those TextTiews

Comment: the idea is that when i know length of surface, i want reduce layout_heigth of surface and apply margintop of table layout, wich iniciatly are same