# Put image to another image in Android

Tags: android, image, position

I need to put image to another image in to the certain position. For example, the first image has resoluiton 1024x768 and I need to put image the second image in position x = 600 and y = 400. Also, I need to change this position by user's choice, for example, for choice A (from spinner) is position XX and for choice B is position XY.
Any idea?
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FrameLayout. Just put bigger image below smallest. And for small image  change margins by user choice.

Here you can find technique how to change margins:

[Change the Right Margin of a View Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472429/change-the-right-margin-of-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm beginner in Android programming, so I don't know how to do it. I tried this code but I'm not able to run it correctly.

Comment: Can you write some code in Java + XML for two pictures and the second picture will be displaced for 100px from left and 100px from top?

Also, I don't know, if your soluiton is correct for me - if I have one 7" tablet and one 3,5" smartphone, image will have same size so it will not fit correctly - or not? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to start coding. Here you can find a good step by step tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/framelayout/android-framelayout-example/

Comment: Simply don't use pixels. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html to understand how to support different screen sizes.