# android: Is it possible to set the margin of each item in a list view programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a listview and I want the items in the list view to have their own margins. I have given the getView() method my adapter code below.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Message msg = getItem(position);

      TextMessageView view = new TextMessageView(getContext(), flag);
           flag = !flag;
           view.setMessage(msg);
           view.setMinimumHeight(50);
           if(flag) {
               view.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
           } else {
               view.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
           }
           return view;

}
```

I want to set the margin through code. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);  //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Could be a duplicate to this in a way...

[Change the Right Margin of a View Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472429/change-the-right-margin-of-a-view-programmatically)